# What is the likelihood function?

Tags: probability, bayesian

When a coin with bias θ for flipping heads is flipped thrice the following result is recorded:
$1st$ Trial: $1$ 
$2nd$ Trial: $0$
$3rd$ Trial: $1$
($1 =$ heads, $0 =$ tails). 
Let this data be represented by x. Would the likelihood function (x|θ) be $$θ^2(1-θ)$$ or $${3 \choose 2}θ^2(1-θ)?$$

Thanks!

Comment: For Bayesian analysis using a conjugate Beta prior, $f(x|\theta) = \theta^2(1-\theta)$ is the appropriate likelihood function.

Answer (score 0):

You know the order of occurrence.

So The likelihood is the first one $\theta(1-\theta)\theta$

---

But for optimization there is no difference since $3 \choose 2$ is just a constant.

Comment: So in what case would it be the second one?

Comment: @abc If you know there is one tail and two heads.

Comment: @abc I'm wondering how the name "abc" was not reserved till now!! :D

Comment: I think you can have any display name you want.

Comment: But I think it must be unique. since you may to mention another one by @abc !

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7118/users-with-the-same-name-is-this-possible @LeilaHatami

Comment: @abc Oops. Thank you. How did you know that?!

Comment: I made a new account and entered the name "abc". Then you commented saying how the name "abc" was not reserved. So I search up whether you could have any display name you wanted because it was unlikely for the name "abc" to not be used by someone else. @Leila

Answer (score 0):

In general, the likelihood is the probability of the observed data given the specified parameter values. But that probability is always defined in terms of a particular event space a.k.a. sample space for the data. *In your case, there are two possible ways of conceiving of the event space.*

One way is think of the space is that there are two possible outcomes, namely $y=1$ (head) or $y=0$ (tail). Then your data consist of $N=3$ data values, $y_1,...,y_3$, and the likelihood of your *set* of  data is $\Pi_i^N \theta^{y_i} (1-\theta)^{y_i}$.

A different way to think of the space is the set of possible total heads $z$ in $N$ flips. When $N=3$, this space has four possible outcomes, namely $z=0$, $z=1$, $z=2$, and $z=3$. Thought of this way, your data is a *single* datum $z$, and its likelihood is ${N \choose z} \theta^z (1-\theta)^{N-z}$.

When you put either one into Bayes rule, you get the same answer because ${N \choose z}$ cancels out.